# Voice mode controlling log in

Tags: ipad

iPad seems to be locked into a voice response mode when touching keys. It was okay a few minutes ago. How I can't get loggin. The numbers/letters do not appear on screen but voice repeats the key touched but doesn't loggin or go pass that screen?  How do it get out of this mode.